# issue with wifimanager.calculatesignalstrenth

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am using the following code to calcualte wifi signals strength:

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();

for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
{    
    int signallevel=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(result.level,10);    
}
```

But it is returning the same value for all the wifi acess points. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep in mind that `WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(result.level, 10)` will return only a number between 0-9. Therefore it is best used for some app which shows a wifi strength indicator (with a few different states like the one normal WiFi indicator in android). Which number is returned depends on the RSSI parameter. So even if the RSSI of two access points are slightly different, this method will yield the same result. If you need finer distinguished results, use either a number higher than 10 or the RSSI values themselves.

Comment: I am getting the same error even when I use a scale of 40. For 50 I am getting a divide by zero arithmetic exception

Comment: @Sarath, this fn has a bug that has never been fixed and which causes the DBZ exeption, but even if you work around that it doesn't really work (returns values outside the range).

Answer (score 2):

here is the code:

```
public int getWifiSignalState(Context ctx) {
    int signalStrength = -1;
    try {
        final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int state = wifi.getWifiState();
        if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
            if(results == null)
                return signalStrength;
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                if(result != null && wifi != null && wifi.getConnectionInfo() != null && result.BSSID != null
                        && result.BSSID.equals(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID())) {
                    int level = 0;
                    level = calculateSignalLevel(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(), result.level);

                    // this is to handle java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
                    if(level != 0 && result.level != 0) {
                        // convert signal strength into percentage
                        int difference = level * 100 / result.level;
                        if(difference >= 100)
                            signalStrength = 4;
                        else if(difference >= 75)
                            signalStrength = 3;
                        else if(difference >= 50)
                            signalStrength = 2;
                        else if(difference >= 25)
                            signalStrength = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ErrorReporter.handleSilentException(ctx, e);
    }

    return signalStrength;
}
```

//This method fix the issue for android 2.3 divide by zero exception

```
public int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) {
    if(rssi <= MIN_RSSI) {
        return 0;
    } else if(rssi >= MAX_RSSI) {
        return numLevels - 1;
    } else {
        float inputRange = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI);
        float outputRange = (numLevels - 1);
        if(inputRange != 0)
            return (int) ((float) (rssi - MIN_RSSI) * outputRange / inputRange);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the function `WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(int RSSI_level, int range)` takes the RSSI level as the first argument and a range for the second argument.

The second argument is easy to understand. Basically, the function returns a value in the range [0 to range-1).

The first argument has to be in the range `MIN_RSSI` and `MAX_RSSI`. Anything `<=MIN_RSSI` returns 0, and anything `>=MAX_RSSI` returns the value you passed as the second argument, minus 1 `(range-1)`.

And, the critical info is: `MIN_RSSI` is defined as a constant, equal to -100 and `MAX_RSSI` is equal to -55. Any value you pass between these two values will be normalized.

As you are passing a value that is above the `MAX_RSSI`, the function always returns the same value.